# Getting all data from ListWidgetItem PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Please have a look at the picture. The bottom widget is a list widget. It works like this. When you click on insert button a new QListWidgetItem will be added dynamically in the bottom ListWidget. Now there are three items in the widget. Each item may contain CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes, lineEdit etc..

[image]

I need to get all those data from the listWidgetItem. Unfortunately, the `listwidgetitem.text()`  is the only way I can retrieve data from the item.
What to do then, to get all these data.

Comment: Are you saying that each ListWidget Item has multiple pieces of data that you want to display and edit?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't (in general) use QListItemWidget for this, but instead a proper QAbstractItemModel-subclass. With that, you can back your listwidget with whatever data you want, and access that data.

There is a utility-class available already called QStandardItemModel which inherits from QAbstractItemModel, and should get you started fast.

[Custom QStandardItemModel with custom data method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518935/custom-qstandarditemmodel-with-custom-data-method)

Comment: Can you please post an example of the above solution, which contain only a CheckBox as an item member.

The above example from the link throws error :(
`PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated`

Comment: have you tried looking for other examples of QAbstractListModel? It is also very well documented.

Comment: Omit the two occurrences of `QVariant()`, e.g. just return `self.listdata[index.row()]`

Comment: It seems that's correct - just return a string, or probably None. PyQt changed it's API there.

Comment: @deets   ListModel is just one dimensional. isn't it? I need more than one widget in a single row. How can I do that using ListModel?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? it is not. QAbstractItemModel can even support full trees with several columns / row, and QListModel supports full table views.

Comment: @deets. There's no such class as `QListModel`, so I assume you meant [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractlistmodel.html#details) - which most certainly is one-dimensional.

Comment: @ekhumoro you are right. However, then the solution is to use QAbstractItemModel.

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple pieces of arbitrary data on a `QListWidgetItem` (indeed, all the **Item** widgets support this).  You need to define a custom role for your data.

```
Data1Role = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
Data2Role = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2

item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
item.setData(Data1Role, 'Any data')
item.setData(Data2Role, 42)

print item.data(Data1Role)
# "Any data"
```

However, this data isn't going to be displayed anywhere on the `QListWidgetItem`.  The only data that is displayed by default is the data set on the `QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole` (which is what `text()` and `setText()` use).

You are probably better off using a `QTreeWidget`, which supports multiple columns (for the multiple pieces of data) and creating a custom subclass of `QTreeWidgetItem`.  If you want the user to be able to edit the data in the table, you're going to need to create a `QItemDelegate` as well to create the `QLineEdits` and `QComboBoxes` for editing the data.